# C#+WPFでウィンドウが終了した原因を調べたい

Tags: c#, wpf

## 状況設定

- C#+WPFでアプリを開発しています
- アプリはメインウィンドウと複数のサブウィンドウで構成されています
- App.yamlで`ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"`と設定しています

## 問題

- 次の2つの状況を考えます

  - サブウィンドウが単独で閉じられた状況
  - メインウィンドウが閉じられたので、サブウィンドウが閉じられた状況
- 上記2つの状況を判別する方法があるでしょうか？

  - できればサブウィンドウ内のメソッドでその結果を知りたいです

Answer (score 2):

メインウィンドウが閉じられた場合、`Application.Current.MainWindow`プロパティが`null`になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事に問題が解決しました。